Astro: Local funciona - Servidor No
Buen día, necesito de su ayuda.
Tengo un proyecto un proyecto en Astro el cual se aloja en un servidor de Netlify, para la parte de la autenticación utiliza Firebase, en mi proyecto local estuvo funcionando correctamentem pero en el servidor no, aparece la siguiente leyenda

Algo salió mal: Error: Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND

Quiero pensar que es por la manera en que esta leyendo la variable
const serviceAccount = {
  type: "service_account",
  project_id: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  private_key_id: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
  private_key: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
  client_email: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  client_id: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID,
  auth_uri: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI,
  token_uri: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI,
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_CERT_URL,
  client_x509_cert_url: import.meta.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_CERT_URL,
};

o a que creen que se deba a que en mi servidor no funcione?
De ante mano, gracias

Obte por mejor utilizar Supabase en vez de Firebase
